# If $\operatorname{grad} F (t,x)= ( f(t,x), g(t,x))$, then why is $\partial_{t}F(t,\lambda(t))= f(t,\lambda(t)) + g(t,\lambda(t))\lambda^{'}(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $\operatorname{grad}$ denote the gradient operator and
$F:U \subseteq \mathbb R^{2} \to \mathbb R$ where $U$ is open. Then assume that $\operatorname{grad} F (t,x)= ( f(t,x), g(t,x))$ for some functions $f, g$ on $U$.

Now define a function $h : I \subseteq \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ with $h(t) = F(t,\lambda(t))$ such that $\lambda: I \to \mathbb R$.

Assume that all of the above function are arbitrarily often differentiable.

Question: Why is $\partial_{t}F(t,\lambda(t))= f(t,\lambda(t)) + g(t,\lambda(t))\lambda^{'}(t)$ ?

Why I am confused:

Since $\operatorname{grad} F (t,x)= ( f(t,x), g(t,x))$, we have that

$\partial_{t}F(t,x)=f(t,x)$ and $\partial_{x}F(t,x)=g(t,x)$, so then I would say

$h^{'}(t)=\partial_{t}F(t,\lambda(t))=f(t,\lambda(t))\lambda^{'}(t)$. I do not understand where the term
$g(t,\lambda(t))\lambda^{'}(t)$ comes from. My rules of differentiation may be failing me here, but any ideas?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: It is better to write $h(t) = F(t,\lambda(t))$, as $h(s) = F(t(s),x(s))$, where $t(s)=s$ and $x(s) = \lambda(s)$. So $\partial_s F(t(s),x(s)) = \partial_tF\cdot  dt/ds + \partial_xF \cdot dx/ds = f \cdot 1 + g \cdot \lambda'$.

Comment: The equality $\partial_{t}F(t,\lambda(t))= f(t,\lambda(t)) + g(t,\lambda(t))\lambda^{'}(t)$ corresponds in fact to a total derivative along some path $(t,\lambda(t))$, so, better write $dF(t,\lambda(t))/dt= f(t,\lambda(t)) + g(t,\lambda(t))\lambda^{'}(t)$ and everything fits.